# DB column value not saving with primary key value after using @PostPersist annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm having three entities which are being saved into the DB. For instance we have 3 entities A, B and C. A is having OneToOne mapping with B and ManyToOne mapping with C which is uni-directional.

```
public class A {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 private int id;
 private String number;

 //Other fields declared

 @PostPersist
 private void onSaving(){

     number = "STU" + id;
   }

 }


public class B {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
int otherID; //primary key for B

//Other fields declared

@OnetoOne(targetEntity = A.class, cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "id") // id is the primary key of class A
private A a;
}


public class C {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
int otherID; //primary key for C

//Other fields declared

@ManytoOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id") // id is the primary key of class A
private A a;
}
```

> Below is the service class for the above entities

```
@Service
public class testService {


@Autowired
private BRepo bRepo; // BRepo is the interface which is extending the JPARepository.

@Autowired 
private CRepo cRepo; // CRepo is the interface which is extending the JPARepository.

@Transactional
public A saveEntity(B b, List<C> c) {
     
     bRepo.save(b);
     cRepo.saveAll(c);

     return b.getA();
  }
}
```

> The entity fields/data are getting perfectly saved into the DB, the only issue I'm facing is with the @PostPersist annotation. My requirement is when save is performed, the **number** field/variable of entity A should be saved as "STU" + id(primary key for A), but in the DB it is saving as STU0 every time I perform save.

I'm unable to find the root cause for this over the internet. Requesting you to please help me debug this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Try to provide a `strategy` for your id (Auto or IDENTITY,...). It's just a suggestion.

Comment: Not working with (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved after I added, strategy as IDENTITY

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```